# VBA - How to reference two separate open workbooks without naming them?

Tags: excel, vba

I have looked around for awhile and cant seem to locate what I need.

Comment: What do you mean with "to reference"?

Comment: "cant seem to locate what I need." - can you explain it though?  Your question is maybe a little too brief...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Refer to Workbooks

If you know there are only two workbooks open, you can use the Index property.

```
Sub ReferToWorkbooks()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook

    Set wb1 = Workbooks(1)
    Set wb2 = Workbooks(2)

    Debug.Print wb1.Name
    Debug.Print wb2.Name

End Sub
```

It is better to loop through all open workbooks and then create references to the ones you need.

```
Sub ReferToWorkbooks2()

    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        Debug.Print wb.Name
    Next

End Sub
```

In case you have a worksheet in your code you use the Parent property:

```
Sub ReferToWorkbooks3()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Debug.Print ws.Parent.Name

    ' or

    Set wb = ws.Parent
    Debug.Print wb.Name

End Sub
```

In case you have a range in your code you use the Parent property twice:

```
Sub ReferToWorkbooks4()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set rng = Range("A1")

    Debug.Print rng.Parent.Parent.Name

    ' or

    Set wb = rng.Parent.Parent
    Debug.Print wb.Name

End Sub
```

You should better explain the scenario where you might need this.